# Batch Request and Usage Limit

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the api sending messages in batches. 
I'm getting many messages with code 400 and 500.

I need to control the time between requests when sending multiple batches?

example: 
messages.get = 5 per second

If I send 100 messages in a batch request, have to wait 20 seconds to send the next batch?

or

need to send 20 requests with 5 messages each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point probably batches of 10 messages each is best.  You can change the per-user limit to 50/sec using the developers console.  Even then, you can exceed the limit for a little bit before you start getting quota errors.  Either way, if you get quota errors for a user you'll want to do some type of backoff for the user.

Comment: I changed the batch size limit to 10. You know if the batch already implementing some request timer? After the batch request i will implement a timer to wait the quota limit, for example: Send 10 messages in a batch and wait 2 seconds to next call.